# Nugetter throwing an initialization error on build server

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild

I am using the NuGetterMultiPkgBuildVersionedTemplate20.xaml template and when I fill out all of the appropriate fields I still get the error below. I created a version seed file as well and It has done nothing for me. What step am I missing?

```
 TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for
 build definition \Foo \Foo: 
 Exception Message: Cannot create unknown type 
 '{clr-namespace:TfsBuild.Versioning.Activities;
 assembly=TfsBuild.Versioning.Activities}VersionAssemblyInfoFiles'.
 (type XamlObjectWriterException)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you've checked the `TfsBuild.Versioning.Activities.dll` file into source control somewhere, then configure the TFS build controller to look there for custom assemblies.

The approach recommended in the TFS Versioning installation guide is:

- create a Team Project called BuildActivities
- create a folder under that named Custom Activity Storage
- add TfsBuild.Versioning.Activities.dll to the Custom Activity Storage folder
- commit those changes

Then, open Team Foundation Server Administration Console, and go to the Build Configuration section. Click Properties next to the Build Controller. Under *Version control path to custom assemblies*, enter the path you created above (in this case, `$/BuildActivities/Custom Activity Storage`). Click OK.

TFS Build should now be able to find and load the assembly.